# Como añadir un producto al carrito en woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Hola comunidad espero se encuentren bien, estaría muy agradecido de su ayuda.

Tengo un Producto en Woocommerce llamado producto de prueba con un id = 25 y su precio en 1. Eso guardado por defecto en la DB. Ahora bien luego de una serie de funciones y calculos obtengo un nuevo valor para el precio, por lo cual me gustaría añadir ese producto al carrito con el nuevo precio calculado. Eh intentado lo siguiente, pero a veces consigo que se añada al carro con un precio de $1, y otras veces me da error, pero de ninguna forma consigo añadir ese producto con el precio modificado.

Cabe mencionar que esto es mediante el desarrollo de un plugin propio que estoy realizando, adjunto código.

cotizador_envios.php

```
// Modifica el precio del producto al añadirlo al carrito
function modificar_precio_producto() {
    if (isset($_POST['custom_price'])) {
        $custom_price = floatval($_POST['custom_price']);
        $product_id = $_POST['add-to-cart'];

        if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0) {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1, 0, array(), array('price' => $custom_price));
        }
    }

    wp_send_json($custom_price);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'modificar_precio_producto', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'modificar_precio_producto_nopriv', 10, 2);
```

Funcion Js dentro de js/cotizador.js del plugin

```
// Obtén el botón de "Añadir al carrito"
    var addToCartButton = document.querySelector('.single_add_to_cart_button');
    
    // Verifica si el botón existe
    if (addToCartButton) {
        // Agrega un evento de clic al botón
        addToCartButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var productId = addToCartButton.value;
            var modifiedPrice = 4000;
            addToCart(productId, modifiedPrice);
        });
    }
    
    function addToCart(productId, modifiedPrice) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("add-to-cart", productId);
        formData.append("quantity", 1);
        formData.append("custom_price", modifiedPrice);
        formData.append('action', 'modificar_precio_producto')
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error('Error al añadir prodcuto al carrito:', error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: el price está en el producto, para modificarlo hay que usar el action `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` como en ese action ya no dispones del custom price lo usual es guardarlo en un metadata al agregarlo al cart mediante el filter `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`